# Running scipy.stats's tests on masked arrays

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

If I run a statistical test on the masked components of a masked array, I suppose it should not work. But when I run the scipy.stats test I get actual numbers out of it.
This is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
x=np.ma.array(np.random.randn(100,2),mask=False)
x.mask[:,0]=True
stats.wilcoxon(x[:,0])
```

Notice that x[:,0] is a set of masked components, so there are no values on which the test could be run.

Does it mean that when running the same test on unmasked components of the same array, say x[:,1], the result is equally unreliable?

Comment: It might be that scipy simply ignores that mask, so you get the same answer regardless of the mask flag value.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you  mean by "the same answer". If there is a mask flag active, then there is no data value stored.

Comment: So there can be no output either.

Comment: The `stats.wilcoxon` function ignores the mask flag and therefore treats the input as non-masked. Probably not every function knows how to deal with masks.

Answer (score 0):

Since SciPy 1.9.0, `scipy.stats.wilcoxon` has respected masked arrays.

The result of your code is:

```
WilcoxonResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

It also has an `axis` argument so you can do:

```py
stats.wilcoxon(x, axis=0)
# WilcoxonResult(statistic=array([  nan, 2399.]), pvalue=array([       nan, 0.66484846]))
```

> Does it mean that when running the same test on unmasked components of the same array, say x[:,1], the result is equally unreliable?

No, the result has been reliable for unmasked components for longer.